# How to implement Continuous integration on asp.net website projects not web application using TFS 17

Tags: asp.net, web, continuous-integration

I have an asp.net website project where want to implement continuous integration using TFS 2017. I really wanted to know how to get rid of config files with environment specific keys.

Currently I have created some config transform files and publish profiles explicitly for each environments. My build definition will create a package after the build. But the package contain config specifically for an environment.

I want to know how to tokenize this thing like we do for web application project.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I want to know is there any way to add parameters.xml along with asp.net website project as we have this option that work fine with web application project.

Answer (score 0):

Here is [an example](http://andrew.lansdowne.me/2016/12/15/using-environment-variables-for-configuration-with-vsts-build-and-release/) about using parameters.xml file in website project and deploy in TFS release.

**Pay attention to:**

Step 2. MSBuild arguments as follows:

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation=”$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\”
```

Step3: In each environment, using [Replace Token step](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens) to replace the values you want to change in web.config file.

**Update:**

As a workaround, you could use the [Unzip step](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=petergroenewegen.PeterGroenewegen-Xpirit-Vsts-Build-Zip) to unzip the package and using the replace token step to change the web.config file. Then zip it again or deploy to IIS directly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  The solution you have mentioned here not solved my problem. ASP.net web site project not fetching values from parameters.xml file attached with the solution. The solution here is more apt for web application project.

Comment: @abhilash did you publish to Azure website? If not, you could use Replace token to change the web.config page directly in each environment without using parameters.xml

Comment: I'm publishing to IIS server. How is that possible to perform replace token? web.config is inside the zipped package. Its not possible to perform Replace token without extracting the package. And if you suggest to unzip it that's not practically possible because my project is more than 4 GB .

Comment: @abhilash Sorry for the late response, I have tested the website and you could unzip the package and using the replace token to change the value, Please refer to the update of my reply.